# Certification of presidential election results in battleground states

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

I have just read [the Atlantic article](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2020/11/what-if-trump-refuses-concede/616424/) which describes a possible constitutional crisis in the USA in aftermath of the current presidential election.

Prevention of the election result certification in the appropriate battleground states is mentioned as a possible strategy to ensure Donald Trump re-election. My question below is most relevant for Michigan, Pennsylvania and Wisconsin, all having D-Governor and R-Legislature.

**Can the certification of the results before the deadline December 8, 2020 really be prevented by refusal of the canvassers to certify the results (on the state or county level)? Are there some means to counteract to this strategy?**

PS. This question was a part of my [previous one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60151/26455) but I was advised to ask it separately.

Comment: A pending lawsuit doesn't prevent a state from moving forward.